# Iterate over 2 lists in java

Tags: java, loops, java-8

```
List<String> listA = new Arraylist();
List<String> listB = new Arraylist();
```

Given above 2 lists, I want to iterate and call the same method on each element.

**Option 1**

```
for(String aStr: listA){
    someCommonMethodToCall(aStr);
    someCommonMethodToCall(aStr);
    ...
}
for(String bStr: listB){
    someCommonMethodToCall(bStr);
    someCommonMethodToCall(bStr);
    ...
}
```

or

**Option 2**

```
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList();
mergedList.addAll(listA);
mergedList.addAll(listB);

for(String elem: mergedList){
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    ...
}
```

or

**Option 3**

I feel the Option 1 should be the best. Is there some Java 8 lambda way to do this? Also, performance wise, would anything better than Option 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can stream the lists and concat the streams into one:

```
Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
    .forEach(elem -> {
        someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
        someOtherMethodToCall(elem);
    });
```

Comment: That's definitely Java 8 way. I assume its performance would be slower than Option 1. What do you think?

Comment: It's possible.  It really doesn't matter: honestly, just pick one.  The performance difference is unlikely to matter, so pick whichever one reads best to you.

Comment: Its performance will be slower, yes, because in addition to the cost of the concat, the lambda adds an object creation cost and another level of indirection (the lambda is an object with an .apply() method that when called, calls someCommon and someOther). But the practical performance hit will be negligible unless this is some often-called inner loop. In most cases, you'd do it because the code is simpler and clearer. The other option would be to factor the shared code into a method, and call that method.

Comment: Performance considerations between for-loop and stream for lists that I assume will have a handful of elements is a waste of time. If the list is supposed to contain millions of items, it should be specified clearly in the question, along with performance expectations.

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8 you can use streams:

```
Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())
        .forEach(this::someCommonMethodToCall);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `peek` method of a `Stream` for the first method call followed by `forEach`:

```
List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
Stream.concat(one.stream(), two.stream())
        .peek(System.out::print)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The following will also work using [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) `tap` method followed by `forEach`:

```
List<Integer> one = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> two = Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6);
LazyIterate.concatenate(one, two)
        .tap(System.out::print)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can chain as many method calls as you need using `peek` or `tap` but what I would recommend is extracting a composite method which makes both method calls.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Option 3,
a DRY approach.
It seems RYL (repeat yourself less), but it is dryer than your current approach.

```
private void doStuff(final String value)
{
    someCommonMethodToCall1(value);
    someCommonMethodToCall2(value);
    ...
}

for (final String currentValue: listA)
{
    doStuff(currentValue);
    ...
}

for (final String currentValue: listB)
{
    doStuff(currentValue);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting variation of shmosel's answer is looping over the stream's iterator directly. Something like:

```java
for (String elem : (Iterable<String>) Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream())::iterator) {
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    ...
}
```

Not sure if it's faster but does avoid defining an inner lambda as well as other issues of creating a new array or duplicating code.

If using often I would create a utility method to reduce line-complexity, `StreamUtils.streamIter()` or something.

```java
for (String elem : streamIter(Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream()))) {
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    someCommonMethodToCall(elem);
    ...
}
```